# babel-plugin-transform-remove-console is not removing console.logs in react website made using create react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

babel-plugin-transform-remove-console is not removing console.logs in react website made using create react app.
I've tried following the guideline of the babel website and tried adding .babelrc file in the directory, but its not removing the console.logs

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` to see if you get what you expect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.